# Continuing errors in hta

Tags: javascript, hta

thanks to every one who taught me that function is case sensitive but now I don't get any errors and nothing happens here is my code

the HTA:

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
  <TITLE>James Tech Calculator</TITLE>

  <HTA:APPLICATION ID="James Tech" APPLICATIONNAME="APP" SCROLL="no" SINGLEINSTANCE="yes">

  </HEAD>

  <BODY>
    <SCRIPT TYPE="text/javascript" SRC=Calc.JS>
      SetSize();
    </SCRIPT>
  </BODY>

  </HTML>
```

and the JavaScript:

```
function SetSize()
{
 window.resizeTo(400,400);
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by giving BOTH the `src` attribute AND local content in your SCRIPT tag? You need two script elements one with `src` and no content, the other with no `src` and the `SetSize()` content.

Comment: Make sure you've correct path for the JS-file (case-sensitive in Win8?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

torazaburo is right, the quickest way to fix your problem is to have two `SCRIPT` tags.

```
<SCRIPT TYPE="text/javascript" SRC=Calc.JS>
</SCRIPT>
<SCRIPT TYPE="text/javascript" >
  SetSize();
</SCRIPT>
```

However, I wouldn't inline the script in the body. I would put it in an event, such as `onload`, for example:

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>James Tech Calculator</TITLE>
<HTA:APPLICATION ID="James Tech" APPLICATIONNAME="APP" SCROLL="no" SINGLEINSTANCE="yes">
</HEAD>
<BODY onload="window.resizeTo(400,400)">
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: Looks bad if the window is resized after load. The best way is to add `resizeTo()` as an inline script to the `head` section even before `<HTA:application>`, though IE10 implicitely moves `<HTA:application>` to the `body` section of the document.